# GAE " no attribute 'HTTPSHandler' " dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the google appengine python SKD from my ubuntu lucid. I have already compiled python2.5. But when I execute any "dev_appserver.py" command with it I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev_appserver.py", line 69, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "dev_appserver.py", line 65, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/rohan/workspace/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 90, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
  File "/media/Ultimate/WebD/django/app_engine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 59, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
  File "/media/Ultimate/WebD/django/app_engine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 24, in <module>
    import fancy_urllib
  File "/media/Ultimate/WebD/django/app_engine/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 328, in <module>
    class FancyHTTPSHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'
```

I have checked the urllib2 moduls of python2.6 and python2.5 but there was no difference in the models defination and HTTPSHandelr is there in python2.5 too. So I guess it is some other sort of error.
I tried to run with the default python2.6 too but then I get the following error:

```
WARNING  2010-09-11 12:08:40,848 datastore_file_stub.py:657] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dev_appserver.py", line 69, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "./dev_appserver.py", line 65, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/rohan/workspace/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 449, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/rohan/workspace/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 426, in main
    static_caching=static_caching)
  File "/home/rohan/workspace/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3820, in CreateServer
    server = HTTPServerWithScheduler((serve_address, port), handler_class)
  File "/home/rohan/workspace/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3840, in __init__
    request_handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 400, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 411, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

It works well in windows and even under wine.
**Update**
Problem with python2.6 solved.
I had configured my apache server for a django deployment on the 8080 and 80 port some time earlier.

But there is still same error with python2.5 isntallation.

Comment: on Unix check the running service on port #using following command, `lsof -i:80` kill that services and try again

Comment: hmm thnx it seems i had configured my apache server for a django on the 8080 port some time earlier :). Just had to change that. But there is still the same error with my phython2.5 installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue...just needed to build all dependencies of python using:

> apt-get build-dep python

python compiles with no error even when all the dependencies are not installed. It just skips the modules which require them and builds python.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for missing HTTPSHandler:

Before you build python 2.5 from source you need to enable ssl-socket by editing Modules/Setup.dist (more info here http://paltman.com/2007/nov/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/)

Comment: You'll also need to have the openssl and libssl-dev packages installed

Answer (score 1):

The method described in this post worked perfectly for me (Ubuntu 11.10).

http://dewbot.posterous.com/installation-of-python-25-and-google-app-engi