# Error with dev_appserver.py of Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu

I 'm trying to use Google App Engine on ubuntu but I got these errors of python SDK

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 78, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 74, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 118, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 68, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 27, in <module>
    import fancy_urllib
  File "/home/user/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 341, in <module>
    class FancyHTTPSHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'
```

**EDIT:** The problem has been solved with your help, thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690932/gae-no-attribute-httpshandler-dev-appserver-py/4203024#4203024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the python you installed didn't have SSL compiled in.  This is the same question basically:

[How do I configure multiple Ubuntu Python installations to avoid App Engine's SSL error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748963/how-do-i-configure-multiple-ubuntu-python-installations-to-avoid-app-engines-ssl)